# what does it mean when running the app again in xcode fixes the issue?

Tags: box2d, openframeworks

Im running ofxBox2d on openframeworks/ ios (though this happens on the desktop version as well).

Occasionally, when I change box2d parameters - simple things like number of circles or joint length, the build will succeed, the app window opens but then closes up or hangs.

Running it again will fix the problem 40% of the time.

has this happened to anyone else before? Seems to be exclusive to ofxBox2d. Does this mean I have to use the deconstructor somehow? (never used it before ... newbie)

Would appreciate any advice. 
Lia

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some variables in your program are being used before initialized. Like this:

```
int x; //x has some garbage.
int y = x + 10;
```

So when you ran multiple times uninitialized variables will have different values. In some cases it can be valid values like zero - the program runs.